# Android - ListView - performItemClick

Tags: android, listview, click

I'm facing some difficults when I try to use the **performItemClick** funcion of the ListView.

All I want to do is to perform a click programatically in the first item of the list.

How can I do that? I looked up that function in the documentation, but I didn't really understand its parameters.

I tried something like:

```
 myListView.performItemClick(myListView.getChildAt(0), 0, myListView.getChildAt(0).getId());
```

But it didn't work `(myListView.getChildAt(0) returns null)`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you solve this problem ?If yes please the write answer.Because I am stuck with same problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a delay for use myListView.performItemClick() after myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 66):

```
mList.performItemClick(
        mList.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
        mActivePosition,
        mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

Where mActivePosition is your click position! 
All the best! :)

Comment: I got best results when using `mList.getChildAt(mActivePosition)` as first parameter.

Comment: where i want to put this code?in setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: @sulai, I think it should be `mList.getChildAt(mList.getHeaderViewsCount()+mActivePosition)`

Comment: This should be after `setOnItemClickListener(...)`(if any).. common thing, yet I succeeded to miss it.

Comment: this does not set the item highlihted if chocieMode is `singleChoice`

Answer (score 29):

This worked for me.

```
listView.performItemClick(
    listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

use the adapter to get the view for the position of the item. The other 2 parameters I didn't want so I left them null.  Leaving convertView null causes the adapter to render a new view. It's a performance issue but since this is only happening once in a while it wont have much effect. I don't need to specify the parent for anything because I'm not using it.

position is just the spot where your item is located.
Additionally these 2 lines of code before your performItemClick create the illusion of having the list item selected. They also ensure the appropriate item is on the screen.

```
listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
listView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last argument in performItemClick be listView.getAdapter().getItemId(position)?

Answer (score 16):

This works best for me. Run this on the main thread.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mList.performItemClick(
                mList.getChildAt(mActivePosition),
                mActivePosition,
                mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
    }
});
```

This is similar to Arun Jose's answer, but it will queue a message to the main thread to give the `ListView` some time to initiate.

Comment: I will use your answer in another answer as comments don't format  code :/. Thanks for the handler

Comment: I don't know why but after orientation change this method does not work

Comment: @JongzPuangput One possible cause: your `ListView` has been re-created and you need to get a new reference for it after orientation change: `mList = getView().findViewById(R.id.list);`

Comment: its woring for me.. I did use BaseAdapter.. Thankx

Comment: This will not always work, since ViewGroup#getChildAt(int index) will work only on the currently visible items on screen, use getView(position, null, null) instead!

Answer (score 5):

I tried the code below and it worked.

```
getListView().performItemClick(null, 0, getListAdapter().getItemId(0));
```

The first parameter (view) can be null.

Comment: while @Arun Jose 's code work fine, setting the first param to null, as proposed here, crashes the app

Comment: Good question. For me it is working properly. Please check the LogCat. Maybe you will find the reason.

Comment: This works for me too. I also found that the id seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I went with

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).performClick();
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Listview (simple array adapter or custom adapter) define listview and other finally make perform click.

For example:

```
 //At onCreate function:

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(List_item.this, list, images));


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)    {
// on click function works
    }
}


int position = 0;
lv.performItemClick(lv.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, lv.getAdapter().getItemId(position));
```

Note: After creating the setOnItemClickListener only you should call
perform click. Otherwise, it will not correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this may be old but this may help :

```
lvList.performItemClick(null, index, lvList.getItemIdAtPosition(index) );
```

NOTE : the first param is null and will still work, if you have a custom adapter, convertView will be filled with custom layout and view and such.

-cheers / happy codings.

Answer (score 1):

```
mList.performItemClick(
    mList.getChildAt(mActivePosition),
    mActivePosition,
    mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

where `mActivePosition` is the position of the child view in List View.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code @sulal proposed, you may place it in onLoadFinished, if you use a LoaderManager. Eg something like

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    //....
    // mSelectedId keeps the currently selected id
    // INVID is an invalid value
    if (mSelectedId == INVID) { // nothing selected
        // sulal's code
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mList.performItemClick(
                        mList.getChildAt(mActivePosition),
                        mActivePosition,
                        mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
                mSelectedId = mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition);
            }
        });            
    }
```

mActivePosition may be 0 (ie position on the first item) or a position kept during eg onPause

Answer (score 0):

At Firstly I tried to use this code in my Fragment(Master/Detail -> NameListFragment)

```
getListView().performItemClick(null, 0, getListView().getAdapter().getItemId(0));
```

But it didn't work. When I did `@Override onStart()` method in fragment and I moved my code to `onStart()`. After that it works properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a unit test case.
Try to use getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync(), to wait the list be loaded, and extend the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547077/testing-a-click-on-an-android-listview-with-activityunittestcase/23895650#23895650).

Answer (score 0):

I just meet this freak problem today  , and  I try me best to deal with it. 
 My condition is , when I first init the layout , I need make some item checked.
    But when I use gridView.getChildAt(position) , always return null. I met this problem before  , caused by Not finishing drawing layout . So I send a post message . handler.postDelayed( .. , ..) , It works.  Thanks who motion this Exception.

Answer (score 0):

**This work for me** 
If you would get weird result when using getView, this is because the list item you want does not exist within visible parts. Use below:

```
private View getViewFromAdapterByPosition(int position, ListView listView) 
{
        View view;
        int firstVisiblePos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastVisiblePos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

        if (position < firstVisiblePos || position > lastVisiblePos) {
            view = listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, listView);
        } else {
            view = listView.getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePos);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

And then,

```
listView.performItemClick(getViewFromAdapterByPosition(index, listView), index, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public static boolean performClicKOnLisViewFromIndex(ListView listView, int index){
        if(listView != null){
            if(listView.getAdapter()!= null && listView.getAdapter().getCount() >0 && listView.getAdapter().getCount() > index ){
                listView.performItemClick(
                        listView.getAdapter().getView(index, null, null),
                        index, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(index));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return  false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`myListView.getChildAt(0)` returns null because used this very soon.

use a delay for it.

or use below code:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private final Context context;
private HashMap<Integer, View> views;

public MyAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    views = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        if(views.get(position) == null)
        {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid, null, false);

            views.put(position, convertView);
        }
        else
            convertView = views.get(position);
    }

    TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.langView);
    tv.setText(languageList.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

and

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        myListView.performItemClick(adapter.getView(position, null, myListView), position, 0);
    }
};

myListView.postDelayed(r, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

just should use `performItemClick()` and it's okay.

```
listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter().getView(listView.getSelectedItemId, null, null), listView.getSelectedItemId, listView.getAdapter().getItemId(listView.getSelectedItemId));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the options solved my problem, so I made an adaptation in my CursorAdapter class.
I defined a global variable in the scope, so I just call the class changing this value and check the cursor position by passing the position value

```
 mProductsAdapter.currentPosition = requiredPosition
```

in my ProductsAdapter builder

```
  var currentPosition = 0
```

in bindView I do the check

```
 if (cursor.position == currentPosition) {
// perform action
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The performClick is probably called before listview was filled, put breakpoint in getView and on performItemClick and check wich is called first

Comment: It is being filled. At least it is not null. I have tried put that piece of code even after the adpter has been set but it still didn't work. This is driving me crazy! Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

`getListView().performItemClick(null, 0, 0)` did the trick for me (for position `0`).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null).performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Dropping Some Experience**.

using listview1.performItemClick, will also trigger your      listview1.OnItemClickListener if you are  using the listener with same listview in your code.

```
Hope It helps
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would get weird result when using `getView`, this is because the list item you want does not exist within visible parts. Use below:

```
private View getViewFromAdapterByPosition(int position, ListView listView) 
{
        View view;
        int firstVisiblePos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastVisiblePos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

        if (position < firstVisiblePos || position > lastVisiblePos) {
            view = listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, listView);
        } else {
            view = listView.getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePos);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

And then,

```
listView.performItemClick(getViewFromAdapterByPosition(index, listView), index, 0);
```

Comment: This is a supplement answer to @Arun Jose 's answer

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
listview.getSelectedView().performClick();
```

Answer (score -5):

This is from Begining Android Games. It creates a simple list of items which you can click to open a new activity. Each list item of course, would have to also be added to the AndroidManifest.xml as a separate activity with a .ListItem# name.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String tests[] = { "ListItem1",
                   "ListItem2",
                   "ListItem3",
                   "ListItem4"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    String testName = tests[position];

    try {
        Class<?> classInstance = Class.forName("your.package.name." + testName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, classInstance);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this is not what I want. I want to perform a click PROGRAMATICALLY in my ListView using the method performItemClick.

Comment: Please remove this answer, it is incorrect! Thanks.