# How to perform autoclick of List Items in listview Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I had a scenario where I need to handle the clicks of each list item one by one with out clicking on that item. Is there a possiblity in which I can achieve this scenario.
Can anyone help me is sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you google "android listview auto click", this came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094268/android-listview-performitemclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mList.performItemClick(
        myList.getAdapter().getView(position,null,null),position,myList.getAdapter().getItemId(position));
```

here position is your click position

or simply you can do this

```
mList.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).performClick();
```

Comment: where should I call this method in onCreateView() or in onResume()

Comment: onCreateView(). when you will start the activity the list items will start to call immediately, dont forget to vote me up :)

Comment: Maybe use same delay after   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, listView.getAdapter().getItemId(0));
   }
  }, 2000);

Comment: This will work for single item that is item in position zero. How to loop through all items by auto click

Comment: This will work for only single item of listview . How should we do for all the items in the list. How can we loop through all the list items with auto click

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your list item and call item.perFormClick()

Comment: This will work for only single item of listview . How should we do for all the items in the list. How can we loop through all the list items with auto click