# Change background color and font color of selected item in listview

Tags: android, listview

- I want to change background color and font color when i select on particular row of listview

MyAdapter class :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    TextView a, b;
    String la, lb;

    String out;
    private int position_visible = -1;


    ListViewAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.arraylist = arraylist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

       a = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.b);

        tvPlaceName.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("a"));

        a = arraylist.get(position).get("a");
        b = arraylist.get(position).get("b");

        if (position_visible == position) {
            tvPlaceName.setBackgroundResource(R.color.divider);
            tvTime.setBackgroundResource(R.color.divider);

        } else {
            tvPlaceName.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            tvTime.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }

        return itemView;
    }

    public void show(int position) { // show a delete button on swipe of list
        // item position
        position_visible = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    }
```

MyList.java :

```
private int posionClicked = -1;

  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



     lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            posionClicked = arg2;
            adapter.show(arg2);
        }
```

list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvPlaceName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#0052a5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large"
        android:background="@color/white"/>


    <TextView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#0052a5" />


</LinearLayout>
```

-- When user select any row of listview ,its background color and font color should be change.

-- all suggestions are heartly welcome.

Comment: Follow this links 1st answer. This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765399/how-to-select-item-in-the-list-view-programmatically/35766765#35766765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Get the text View and set the font as shown below
        TextView tv_the = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "condenced.ttf");
        tv_the.setTypeface(face);

        tv_the.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        //And set backgroundColor of whole item by following
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7A83"));
    });
}
```

try this and let me know if it work.

Comment: what about text color ?

Comment: This will work but if you need only single selection then you need to reset back all other items to default state before set another selection. I will suggest you selector xml so make the code little cleaner and easier.

Comment: Done check the answer

Comment: Basically you need to give the id to main tag of the adapter's layout and when you click on the view then the color will change accordingly

Comment: yet not correct. it is reacting weird.. anonymous row background is changing rather than selected

Comment: how to deselect when another row is clicked

Comment: @Rakshit Nawani ,, can u tell me how to deselect when another row is clicked

Comment: @tiger in starting create an integer, when you make a click increase the value of it. and then make a check inside the click listener that is the counter is even then do stuff else do other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You Can set drawable files as background and textColor to the TextView

**Example:**

```
 android:background="@drawable/selected_background"
 android:textColor="@color/selected_text"
```

*selected_background.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"  />
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/darkGrey" />
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
```

*selected_text.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
 <item android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
   posionClicked = arg2;
   adapter.show(arg2);
   TextView text_item = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.id_of_item_listview);
   tv_the.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    }
```

Try it!