# Why are some listview items not getting selected?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listview that uses base adapter and two layouts to display items. i have implemented multichoicemodelistener on this listview.

The issue is when i long press listview items, some are getting selected while others are not. i have realized that the ones getting selected are using a different row layout from the ones not getting selected.

**layout of listview rows that are getting selected.** >>>>  **LAYOUT 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.x.y.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

       <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#020202"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout of listview rows that are not getting selected** >>>> **LAYOUT 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

    <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#020202"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**how i have implemented multichoice mode listener**

```
list_View.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new Selector());
```

Selector class

```
private class Selector implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        int checkedCount = list_View.getCheckedItemCount();
        Log.d("Selector","checked items are "+checkedCount);
        mode.setSubtitle(checkedCount+" selected");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
        adapter.removeSelection();
    }
}
```

**Why** are some of my listview items using **LAYOUT 2** not getting selected? whenever i click any item using that layout, no selection occurs and even debug info isn't been printed out.

Comment: Try this it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765399/how-to-select-item-in-the-list-view-programmatically/35766765#35766765

Comment: @AnandKumarJha  it's a good method but not acceptable in my situation. the method am using is the best and appropriate if u can help solve the bug in it.

Comment: @AnandKumarJha     i have realized the problem. look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized what was making listview items using **LAYOUT 2** to be unselectable. the problem was that i had made textview's text in **layout 2** to be selectable.

**inside layout 2**

```
   <Textview
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#020202"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
     />
```

**i changed it to**

```
<Textview
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#020202"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
     />
```

change is `android:textIsSelectable="false"`

And all listview's  items using this layout became selectable.

**SO WHY DOES IT AFFECT LISTVIEW ITEM SELECTION?**

According to android docs

> When you call this method ( in Xml `android:textIsSelectable="true"`
>   or programmatically `textview.setTextIsSelectable(true)`), it sets the
>   flag focusable,focusableInTouchMode,clickable and longClickable to the
>   same value.

This means if i set `android:textIsSelectable="true"':

- `android:longClickable` is automatically set to **true** and according to android docs

> SetLongClickable enables or disable long click events for this view.
>   when a view is long clickable, it reacts to the user holding down the
>   button for a longer duration than a tap. this event can either launch
>   the listener or a context menu.

- `android:clickable` is also automatically set to **true** and according to android docs

> setClickable enables or disables click event for this view. when a
>   view is clickable,it will change its state to "pressed" on every
>   click.

Therefore longclicks, and click events get consumed by textview [they are passed to this textview] instead of listview thus listview item  selection with this textview fails to occur.