# Highlight the selected item in Horizontal List view

Tags: android, horizontallist, selectlistitem

By default i need to show one item as highlighted in horizontal list view and when the user selected another item in the horizontal list view i want to highlight that item(removing the earlier and highlight the currently selected) for that i'm trying with the following code,in my adapter

Adapter:-

```
 int selectedIndex;
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v = convertView;
   v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.hlist_rowitem, null);

  if (position == selectedIndex) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#abcdef"));
 }
}
```

and after selecting another item from activity in from the list view what to do in activity to change highlighting position of the item.

Activity:-

```
int sIndex;
sIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);
hlAdapter = new HSelectedAdapter(InsuranceCard.this, rowItems, sIndex);
hListView.setAdapter(hlAdapter);
hListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
 //other code goes here
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd would use a [color state list resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and have the ListView handle the selection with [setSelection(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29).

The color list would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#aabbcc"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:color="#fedcba"/> <!-- selected -->
    <item android:color="#abcdef"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and it should be set as background of the `R.layout.hlist_rowitem` or as `listSelector` on the listview.

Edit:
To change the selection when receiving a click event:

```
hListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        hListView.setSelection(position);
    }
});
```

The ListView will deselect the old/default item and selects the new item at the specified position.

Edit 2: By default the ListView don't have a choice mode set so make sure you either set it in xml or in code: `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

Comment: then how to remove earlier selected item?

Comment: You don't :) The ListView only highlights one selected item so every time you select a new item the old item is deselected.

Comment: If you observe my question in the above i'm setting a default item as selected and now the problem is removing the default selection and applying new selected item.

Comment: So you want only one item to be highlighted as selected? and when you select a new item you want the old to be deselected? If that's the case you can easily use the selector. Just call listView.setSelection(newPosition) whenever you want to deselect the old item and select the new item.

Comment: then how to pass it to the adapter and how to update it in onclick

Comment: I edited my answer with an onClick. With my approach I don't have to pass anything to the adapter.

Comment: by default i need to set a selected item then how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56954/discussion-between-delblanco-and-harish).

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this in two ways.

1. manually clear all item and set selected in onItemClick()

   ```
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
               long arg3) {

           for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
           View item = listview.getChildAt(i);
           if (item != null) {
               item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected);
           }
           arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
       }

       }
   });
   ```
2. use selector and let listview do itself.

/drawable/selector_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected"/>

</selector>
```

and add `android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_list"` to your listview

Comment: need to show one item as it is default selection and when the user changes according to that change the selection.

Comment: use this [How to tap ListView item programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16278023/1608643)

Comment: hey thank for your answer its work. but when i click on first and scroll then last item also selected. when i second item select then last of two item also selected.

Comment: @tejshah I think it happens due to recycling. try viewholder pattern in getView() method of adapter.

Answer (score 0):

add listitemclick.xml
in your drawblw folder this is the code.
    
    
         
         
         
    
2)then in your hlist_rowitem.xml set background="@drawable/listitemclick"

Comment: then how to remove earlier selected item?

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:
1)declare one boolean array.
public static boolean ClickItem[];
2)inside oncreate 
ClickItem=new boolean[your array size];
 Arrays.fill(ClickItem, false);

in your adapter write this code
a)
    if ClickItem[pos]
    {
      v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#abcdef"));
    }else

a)
       v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Arrays.fill(ClickItem, false);
            ClickItem[pos]=true;

            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

Comment: 1)it is not multiple selection 2) what is arrays.fill() and how you are getting that into the adapter.