# Android custom listview adapter to stay highlighted selected item

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my `listview`. What I want to do is when I click an item in the `listview`, it should remain highlighted, and when I click another item, new item should be highlighted.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public void setSelection(int position) {
    if (selectedPos == position) {
        selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;
    } else {
        selectedPos = position;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Adapter GetView:**

```
if (position == selectedPos) {
  // your color for selected item
     viewHolder.tvTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_blue));
     viewHolder.tvDetails.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_blue));
 }
else {
  // your color for non-selected item
     viewHolder.tvTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
     viewHolder.tvDetails.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
    }
```

**Activity:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        episodesAdapter.setSelected(position);
     }
 });
```

This is working as expected, but the problem is with `notifyDataSetChanged`, it's delaying the time to highlight item that is being selected next. What should I do to automatically get it highlighted? Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

Update:
I tested and it took 8-10secs before a new item is highlighted. There is a slight delay in highlighting an item.

Comment: have a look here for a possible solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted

Comment: @Tasos thanks but what I want is to just highlight the textviews not the row

Comment: ok sorry. do you use an array for the listview?

Comment: I have an arraylist (records/items) from server

Comment: ok so simply add to the array for all items (selected = false) and then when you click on the item set (selected = true) for that position in the array which is the same as the items position in the listview and change the colors. Lastly in your adapter you do a check ( if selected = true then change colors  else do nothing)

Comment: @Tasos can you post sample code?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630538/highlight-the-selected-item-in-horizontal-list-view/24630894#24630894

Comment: @KetanAhir I've done this but not exactly what I'm looking for