# Error - with listview.performItemClick()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, click

I need to call a method `listview.setOnItemClickListener ()` and when I found [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278023/4393776) on the solution, then I try realize it , but get an error with it at any `mActivePosition`, I can not understand what the problem, is here logcat:

```
12-28 05:33:39.324  13066-13066/com.example.SmsService E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.SmsService, PID: 13066
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.SmsService.VideoView$3.getView(VideoView.java:140)
        at com.example.SmsService.VideoView.onCardboardTrigger(VideoView.java:217)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardActivity$SensorListener.onCardboardTrigger(CardboardActivity.java:84)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.sensors.MagnetSensor$TriggerDetector$1.run(MagnetSensor.java:141)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

there is problem string :

```
listview.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null),
```

And there is all my class, [gist](https://gist.github.com/diha-o/d56781630f0a656833f5). Сan anyone tell me why this any typing errors and how it can fix that would work?

Comment: please i do not really understand you can you come again, and its ok to pass null, but for some reasons its bad so just put your listiview in as a parent.. the listview is the parent not the listview's parent.. get me? and also i didnt understand what you said about the performclick and performitemclick

Comment: on a second thought, use null..as the parent ok..its ok..

Comment: @Elltz, `performclick and performitemclick`- as I said I need to perform a method setOnItemClickListener that would go to the next item in the listView, but when I perform  `performclick and performitemclick` then get(go) in method getView.

Comment: @Elltz, from the response that gave the user **HBizhi** I have not worked  `performclick and performitemclick`

Comment: nevermind, you see the line 140 in your code in the getview?? do this rather replace this with that code okay `View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_leyout, parent, false)` and clean, rebuild and run again, the error should be gone

Comment: @Elltz, yes it works , but still in the performance I get in `getView` method but `listview.setOnItemClickListener` not be carrying out. I need to perform `listview.setOnItemClickListener` that would go to the next item in the list `listView`

Comment: can you please explain what you want to do in detail, as in what you want the listivew to do,  becuase i see two listivew attached to the same adapter right? so please explain with detail what you want to do

Comment: also i want to explain something to you `listview.performItemClick(listview.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null),1,listview.getAdapter().getItemId(1)` the parameters where you placed **1** must be the position of the click event so you must put `mSelectedItem+=1;` there, or?

Comment: @Elltz, I think it is clear that I am only a novice programmer , but `mSelectedItem+=1` I understand , and the transition to the element is not carried out

Comment: @Elltz, Here is another topic that I raised , because there is already a whole day can not solve your problem, you mey see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681266/move-to-the-next-item-android-horisontallistview

Comment: @Elltz, I also tried to somehow directly call the method `OnItemClickListener ()` so trying to make something of this `listview.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick((AdapterView<?>) listview.getParent(),(ViewGroup)listview.getParent(),2, listview.getAdapter().getItemId(2));`

Comment: last question before i try to answer, does the background color change? after you perform click?

Comment: @Elltz, `background color change` - no, why should he change?

Comment: because yo have this `retval.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE` so i was wondering if it changes, so i can know if really your getview method is called fully or not..okay..

Comment: @Elltz, I do not understand correctly , but the background color changes back , that picture is what it looks [like](http://pixs.ru/showimage/xdzqUAkngj_2470358_15358904.jpg)

Comment: @Elltz, everything works well , but like I said I just want to figure out how to move to the next item in the list listView

Comment: oh ok, good, if that's the case then use `listview.setSelection(number);` that is if you know the next item position.. but if you do not know the next item position `listview.setSelection(getPositionForView(getSelectedView())+1);` or simpily this `listview.setSelection(getSelectedItemPosition()+1)` or you could scroll to the next item by `smoothScrollToPosition(int position);`

Comment: @Elltz, I take you it's but you don't see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681266/move-to-the-next-item-android-horisontallistview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you trying to use `performClick()`?

If calling `performItemClick` on the `onCreate()` method, there would be `NullPinterException`,

Because the screen is not fully visible to the user.

Try calling this method in [onWindowFocusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) like below:

```
listview.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null).performClick();
```

Instead of that you can also use same delay after:

```
Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ 
    @Override public void run() {
                  listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter()
                      .getView(1, null, null), 0, listView.getAdapter().getItemId(1)); 
               } 
}, 2000);
```

**Important note: This will work for single item that is item in position 1.**

Also, If your question is all about using `onWindowFocusChanged` try checking this:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

          if(hasFocus) 
             Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
    }
```

Comment: yes you are right saying can give an example of the code because I do not fully understand how it should look , and yes we all have - that learn )

Comment: ,I see, and try it all except onWindowFocusChanged, but it still does not work and gives the same error

Comment: Please try `onWindowFocusChanged` and paste the result. Also make sure of the index I mentioned as an important note above. If you have only one Item, don't forget indexes are starting from `0`. I edited the code above, changing `getItemId(0)` to `getItemId(1)`, as you are using index one not zero

Comment: `listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter()                      .getView(1, null, null(you do not know the parent??)), 0, listView.getAdapter().getItemId(1));`

Comment: @Elltz, `..null(you do not know the parent??)..` what do tou mean?

Comment: @HBizhi, how it' `onWindowFocusChanged` help me I do not understand ?I also need to perform actions when I interact with a magnet instead of a window ?

Comment: @Elltz, and I need to get a parent?

Comment: @Elltz, I try like `(ViewGroup)listview.getParent()` but still not work(

Comment: @Elltz, when I call `performClick()` and `performItemClick` it's call method `getView()` but not `setOnItemClickListener`