# Move to the next item - Android- Horizontallistview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-view, listviewitem

The problem is that when I call from my `ListView` method `performItemClick()` I did not turn to the method `setOnItemClickListener()`, and get into a method `getView ()`.
I need to call a method `setOnItemClickListener()` which relate to my `ListView`, I tried to do this with `listview.performItemClick ()`, but nothing happened . In fact , my problem is that I just have to go to my next item in the list (listview), but there is a problem , because I have a list of looped `Integer.MAX_VALUE ;`. Because I just need to go to the next item on the list, I tried to do `setSelection(mSelectedItem)`but in my code I use `HorizontalListView` and when I looked into this class saw:

```
    @Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
}
```

means that this method does not work.
 Why is this happening and how I could fix this?This is my [class](https://gist.github.com/diha-o/83c3a1876a6863a24e98).

Comment: Which class does your `HorizontalListView` extends?

Comment: @joao2fast4u, `AdapterView<ListAdapter>`

Comment: https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView. That `HorizontalListView` implementation has `setSelection()` working. Have you tried it?

Comment: @joao2fast4u, thank's for link, now try.