# Android Custom Listview Programmatically Click Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a custom single choice listview. I want to call `ItemOnClickListener` programmatically. I am using `android:listSelector="#47D149"` property in my xml. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094268/android-listview-performitemclick). `performItemClick` function is working but doesn't change the background of list item.

What should I do?
Any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the item selected programmatically?Or do you want the item to **remain selected** once you have the item?

Comment: Yes I want the item selected programmatically. But selected item background is not painted. @Droidekas

Comment: Well what i normally do is put the background  color logic in my adapter to indicate selected item.Is that too much of a change for you?

Comment: @Droidekas Yes it works but xmls which have colors shouldn't inside "<selector></selector>" tag. I was trying to do in "<selector></selector>" tags all day. So, they should be in Shifar Shifz answer. Now Should I make green Shifar Shifz answer?

Comment: if his answer solves your problem. then yes you should :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SAMPLE**

*ListView*

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_container"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlBanner"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/nyc_black"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/border_black"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector" >
```

*drawables/item_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed"></item>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed"></item>
</selector>
```

*drawables/item_normal.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
     >
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/black"
        />
</shape>
```

*drawables/item_pressed.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
     >
     <solid 
         android:color="@color/red"
         />
</shape>
```

Try the above sample. :) tell me if it works

Comment: I dont have selector xml, list selector is a color

Comment: Sorry but no, performItemClickfunction worked but the listview item ui not changed

Comment: Set android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector" as custom listview row background

Comment: @kalidossrajendran sorry I see after I answer my own the question. But this is the answer. Thank you

Comment: should I select your answer as correct answer ? @ShifarShifz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just take care of it in your adapter itself?

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        if(this.getItem(position).isChecked()){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
        }

        final View tempFinalView = convertView;
        tempFinalView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                              @Override
                                                              public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                  if (getItem(position).isChecked()) {
                                                                      getItem(position).setChecked(false);
                                                                      tempFinalView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                                                                  } else {
                                                                      getItem(position).setChecked(true);
                                                                      tempFinalView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pressed);
                                                                  }
                                                              }
                                                          }
        );

   return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you dont want to add another variable to the item.You could use the tag feature instead.

Just **set** and **get**  the tag.

private static int VIEW_TAG=99;

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

```
    if((Boolean)convertView.getTag(VIEW_TAG)){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
    }

    final View tempFinalView = convertView;
    tempFinalView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              if (getItem(position).isChecked()) {
                                                                  convertView.setTag(VIEW_TAG,new Boolean(false));
                                                                  tempFinalView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                                                              } else {
                                                                  convertView.setTag(VIEW_TAG,new Boolean(true));
                                                                  tempFinalView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pressed);
                                                              }
                                                          }
                                                      }
    );
```

return convertView;
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found the solution. :) @Shifar Shifz answer, dont use

`android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector"`

Instead of it, add this drawable xml to your row.xml layout as background

`android:background="@drawable/item_selector"`