# Android ListView performitemclick (not position)

Tags: android, android-listview, click

How can I change the code below?

this is actually:

```
lv.performItemClick(lv, 1, lv.getItemIdAtPosition(1));
```

I want this

```
lv.performItemClick(lv, "lorem ipsum", lv.getItemIdAt**Position**("lorem ipsum"));
```

Comment: see this link you can understand where is the  problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094268/android-listview-performitemclick

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter` you can grab the adapter and use `getPosition`. Also the `View` parameter refers to the child view within the ListView, not the ListView itself.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) lv.getAdapter();
int position = adapter.getPosition("lorem ipsum");

lv.performItemClick(lv.getChildAt(position), position, lv.getItemIdAt(position));
```