# How to test items in a listview

Tags: android, unit-testing, listview

I am still figuring out Android unit tests. Also, still somewhat new to android and so some of the UI components puzzle me a little. I have inherited a complex android application with no unit tests and am attempting to write unit tests as I work on things.

I have an activity that extends ActionBarActivity and is basically a menu. The activity contains one listview and each item has an icon. Clicking an item in the list view takes you to another activity.

The items on the listview are conditionally added. I have been able to access the listview, and make sure the proper items are added in the proper condtions.

Now I want to go through the list view one at a time and click the item and make sure the right activity is getting launched.

I've read the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-ui-testing.html, but it seems to me that dynamic list views are a little different since the list view has a name, but it's individual items all have the same name, right?

So how do I access the individual rows of my listview and click them to check my event?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom listview Then it could be done in the ListAdapter. I think the Right place is in the GetView function and also get Id. 
You can track them , as when they get Id or when they get view.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I'm using         ListView listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        SimpleAdapter listAdapter = (SimpleAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
        View view = listAdapter.getView(0, convertView, listAdapter); What do I use for convertView and parent on getView()? I think listAdapter is the parent.

Comment: I was talking about the custom listview

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to programatically click an individual item from a list view as part of an automated test, I think this post will be helpful. [Android - ListView - performItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094268/android-listview-performitemclick)