# Highlight first item of listview when created

Tags: java, android, listview, highlight

I am able to change the background of a selected item in a listview. I want the first item's background highlighted when the list is created.  The code below gives an error when I try to perform a "performItemClick".

I have seen suggestions to modify my getView in the array adapter. However, I get the error "no default construction in Android.widget.ArrayAdapter when I try to create the class MyCustomAdapter in my java code.

So, if I need to create an extention of my ArrayAdapter class to do this, how do I get around this error. If there is another way I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

```
package com.hofficer.aclsfast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class NarrowChild extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_narrow_child);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

        //fix orientation

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        createList();
    }
    /*
    class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    }*/

    void createList(){
        String[] narrowChoices = {"aFib/Flutter", "Narrow Cmplx Tachycardia", "PSVT", "Junctional Tachycardia", "Multifocal Tachycardia"};

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, narrowChoices);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.narrowListView);

        listview.setAdapter(theAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                //clear menu and highlight selected item
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    listview.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                listview.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
        });
        Boolean result = listview.performItemClick(listview,0,0);   //THIS GIVES ERROR NULL POINT EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a CustomArrayAdpter for this ?

Comment: How do I do this? I've tried to make a class within my Activity class, but I keep getting the error I mentioned in my initial question.

Comment: Your requirement is to highlight the first row always right?

Answer (score 1):

in your MyCustomAdapter you have to override the one or more of the constructors of ArrayAdapter or create your own. and example of custom Adapter is :

```
    public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Weather data[] = null;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

more info from the [source](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

in your case you need to check the position if it is 0 and then return the desired item.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out doing something similar to what you said. Your comment is very helpful and thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but can't you just call `listview.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);` instead of `Boolean result = listview.performItemClick(listview,0,0);`?

Comment: I've tried that but I get a nullpoint error.  I can access getChildAt from within the onItemClick routine, but not anywhere else without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Boolean result = listview.performItemClick(listview.getAdapter().getView(0),0,0);
```

or:

```
Boolean result = listview.performItemClick(listview.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null),0,0);
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094268/android-listview-performitemclick) and check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View,%20int,%20long)).

**EDIT**

I think your problem is the getChildAt() method. You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children) question.

Comment: I had tried this and variations of your suggestion.  Still no luck.